# I want my bot to send direct message to a user ONLY if the user's direct message

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am not making a command, i just want to send a message whenever a user dm's the bot. Any message. here's the code i wrote but it is specific for a command-

```
client.on("messageCreate", (message) => {
  if (message.content === "hi") {
    message.member.send("Hello")
  }
})
```

Comment: What are "dm's"?

Comment: @Reporter Direct Messages. Like a text or chat message, but directed to a single person instead of a group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To execute a piece of code when a user DMs a bot, all you have to do is add the `DIRECT_MESSAGES` intent to your client. Then you can modify your current code to check if the message sent was in a DM and then execute a piece of code:

```
client.on("messageCreate", (message) => {
  if (message.channel.type === 'DM') {
    // Execute something
  }
})
```